# How do I pass an array to a function and NOT have it changed outside the function?(array no global)

Tags: c, arrays, function

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

fun(int porra[])
{  
   porra[0]=-1;
}


int main()
{
  int vec[1];
  vec[0]=0;
  fun(vec);
  printf("%d",vec[0]);
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Is it supposed to print -1 instead of 0?
If so, is there a way to copy the array to the function without running a for by the array?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I pass an array to a function and NOT have it changed outside the function?

You might like to wrap the array in a `struct` and pass an instance of this  `struct` by value.

This for example this could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct array_wrapper
{
  int vec[1];
}

fun(struct array_wrapper aw)
{  
  aw.vec[0] = -1;
  printf("copy of array's 1st element inside fun(): %d\n", aw.vec[0]);
}

int main(void)
{
  struct array_wrapper aw;
  aw.vec[0] = 0;

  printf("original array's 1st element prior to calling fun(): %d\n",
    aw.vec[0]);

  fun(aw);

  printf("original array's 1st element after having returned from fun(): %d\n", 
    aw.vec[0]);
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way in C to pass arrays by value because they "decay"  to pointers to their first element when they are passed as a parameter.

But there is a trick: Declare a struct which contains an array. A struct is passed by value, including the array, which is weird if you think of it (and didn't work when I learned C because structs couldn't be function arguments). After all, structs are a lot like arrays, the elements just having different types.

(For example code, see alk's answer above, he was faster.)

Comment: "*because structs couldn't be function arguments*" dxxm, that's truely been long ... ;-) - anyways 1+ for the background is missed in my answer. But .. err "*structs are a lot like arrays*" ... - not really, as you just pointed out yourself!

Comment: @alk Both are compound types, obviously. A struct with elements of the same type will (packed) have the same memory layout as an array and produce the same code for access (I suspect). In fact, if C didn't have structs and unions one would emulate structs by arrays of elements big enough to hold the biggest desired type and name the offsets...

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is correct: the function argument is the value that allows accessing the array to which it points. If you want to have the original array unchanged, you would have to either create a 'deep copy" of it (i.e. copy every element) inside that function, or to make sure that you get a copy of the original array, as suggested in other posts.